# are jQuery and ASP.NET MVC 3 really cross browser?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html

can I assume that a solution based on ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor and HTML 5) and jQuery will be fully cross browser and cross platform?

I know I should only use jQuery for the selectors and events and not mix it with old fashion raw javascript, if we follow this advice will we end up with a full cross browser app working in IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera with no issues and on iPad as well?

As anybody done anything like this really and got good results?

we plan to use the DevExpress MVC extensions 2011 v1 or higher ( when available ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cross browser development has nothing to do with the server (ASP.NET MVC). It's about writing standards compliant HTML, CSS and JS.

The JavaScript framework you use is irrelevant.

The main problem is patching olding browsers to emulate newer features. I recommend you use

- [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)
- [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)
- [Flow](http://flowjs.com/download/)
- [Selectivr](http://selectivizr.com/)

Those 4 libraries will patch most older browsers to become ES5, CSS3 and DOM3 compliant.

You will still need a few more patches for advanced DOM features.

> As anybody done anything like this really and got good results?

Yes, the people who write *unit tests* and do browser compliant testing confirm that their website are cross browser compliant.

You **DO NOT** write code and assume it works. Test your browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of an open question as cross browser issues can still result no mater what framework and JavaScript library you chose to use, as you are in control of your markup and CSS.

We use MVC 3 and jQuery at work and have to support IE (back to version 6), Firefox and Chrome. We don't openly specifically support (or test on) Safari & Opera but I would imagine there would be no issues.

The only real cross browser issues I tend to get are with CSS and markup. You can try and mitigate this by using a CSS layout system like the [960 grid](http://960.gs/) (although some people don't like them mind).

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC is a server language and renders HTML. With ASP.NET MVC you can control the HTML that is rendered.

jQuery is cross browser, but not all functionality might work with mobile devices. But there's an additional framework for that: [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).